# How to grab audio from windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio, screen-grab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capturing Audio Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578697/capturing-audio-out)

We can get frame (current monitor screen data) buffer via for example [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28VS.85%29.aspx) but I wonder if we can do something similar with currently playing sounds? Is there any function for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578697/capturing-audio-out